# How to fetch the mat-options from a mat-select dropdown in karate

Tags: karate

I need to fetch all the values from the states dropdown and compare it with a list of Indian states to validate if all the states are present.

In selenium , we use the getOptions() method. I am wondering if there is a similar method in karate. Here is the dropdown html

[image: html code for states]

I am able to find help on how to select the options using karate not on how to get all the options.

Answer (score 0):

I think this may work for your case, refer docs: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/tree/master/karate-core#scriptall

```
* def list = scriptAll('.mat-option-text', '_.textContent')
```

To select options, please refer: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/tree/master/karate-core#drop-downs

Comment: tried this but it does not work. The list is not printing any value.

Comment: @shilpa sorry I give up. if you provide a live url others may be able to help you